# Hazelcast user code deployment with Jcache

Tags: hazelcast, jcache

I have a hazelcast Member that uses Jcache. I am using CacheLoader and CacheWriter for Jcache.

On another member that is clustering, I am getting an exception that one of the Jcache CacheLoader classes can't be loaded. The cacheloader is defined as an internal private static class.

Below is what my usercode deployment config looks like on both members.

```
<user-code-deployment enabled="true">
    <class-cache-mode>ETERNAL</class-cache-mode>
    <provider-mode>LOCAL_CLASSES_ONLY</provider-mode>
</user-code-deployment>
```

The exception I get is:

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class app.cache.HzAuthCacheManagerImpl$DefaultCacheLoader from other members.
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:83)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:72)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class app.cache.HzAuthCacheManagerImpl$DefaultCacheLoader from other members.
    at com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.impl.ClassLocator.tryToGetClassFromRemote(ClassLocator.java:157)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.impl.ClassLocator.handleClassNotFoundException(ClassLocator.java:95)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.UserCodeDeploymentService.handleClassNotFoundException(UserCodeDeploymentService.java:89)
```

I don't get any exception on the member that has HzAuthCacheManagerImpl defined.

Is there anything wrong in my configuration or something else is needed to get usercode deployment working with JCache?

Comment: Can you also post some additional info: cache configuration, how do you configure and obtain the cache on each member (programmatically, declaratively or dynamically via `CacheManager.createCache`)?

Comment: I am doing it programmatically.
cachingProvider = HazelcastServerCachingProvider.createCachingProvider(hazelcastInstance);
        cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager();
        tokenPolicyBeanCache = getReadThroughCache("tokenPolicyCache", String.class,AuthTokenPolicyBean.class);
        userCache = getReadThroughCache("userCache",String.class,UserBean.class, new UserCacheLoader());

Comment: Can you post the actual `Cache` configuration? This must be defined somewhere within your `getReadThroughCache` method. As a side note on a different topic, `HazelcastServerCachingProvider#createCachingProvider` is not public API (class is in `impl` package). See an example of obtaining a `CacheManager` backed by an existing `HazelcastInstance` here http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.4/manual/html-single/index.html#reusing-existing-code-hazelcastinstance-code-with-the-default-code-cachemanager-code

Comment: I was doing it wrong on my side. I'll close the question.